# How to change to script directory in shell?

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a python script that resides in the directory of my shell script, but I cannot find out how to dynamically change directory in the shell script, so I could execute it reliably.

Most solutions I've seen are using features available in bash, but I can only use shell since I am using `alpine` and do not want to install bash. The shell script is something like this:

```sh
export FLASK_APP="./app.py"
export FLASK_RUN_HOST='0.0.0.0'
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
flask run
```

And `app.py` is in the same directory of my script.

Comment: So if not `bash`, which shell are you using? `dash`? Some other?

Comment: Relating https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/4957508

Comment: @mivk i'm using simple `sh` which i think is named shell?

Comment: @FarhoodET. `sh` is probably a symlink to the real shell. You could try `which sh` and/or `ls -l $(which sh)` or `ps -p $$` to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running Alpine Linux which uses the [`ash` shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) by default:

> Note: By default Alpine Linux uses the ash shell <sup>[*](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Change_default_shell)</sup>

So try this, adapted to `ash` from the one-liner in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/111036):

```sh
my_dir="$( cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd )"
echo "I'm running in $my_dir"
```

It works for me in Ubuntu's `dash`, which is a derivative of `ash`.